# Struggling with Facebook.php

Tags: facebook

I have downloaded the latest version of facebook.php from here:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

...and have uploaded facebook.php and base_facebook.php and I have my correct api and api secret.

I have followed the exact code from phpfour here:

http://phpfour.com/blog/2010/05/quick-start-on-new-facebook-php-sdk-iframe-based/

And yet I am still gettng this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession()

What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

TheBounder.

Comment: Can you please post your code?Anyway that blogpost is a little old, maybe (as the author of the blog stated) you should check the documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [this](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=346031) post  (look answer number 6) getSession no longer exists in the API and that is the reason why you are getting the error.